# Python RegEx Replace - Inverting the Search removing too much

Tags: python, regex-negation

Working in Python 2.7.  I'm attempting to remove from a string all things not databases and tablename combinations.  I'm using regex for this, and unintentionally removing all the whitespace (which I need to keep to separate the values)

```
s = "replace view dw1.tbl1_st as select dw2.tbl1_st.col1, dw2.tbl1_st.col2, "
s = s + "dw2.tbl1_st.col3,  dw2.tbl1_st.col4  dw2.tbl1_st.col5, "
s = s + "dw2.tbl1_st.col6, dw2.tbl1_st.col7  dw2.tbl1_st.col15, dw2.tbl1_st.col8, "
s = s + "dw2.tbl1_st.col9, dw2.tbl1_st.col10,  dw2.tbl1_st.col11, dw2.tbl1_st.col12, "
s = s + "dw2.tbl1_st.col13, dw2.tbl1_st.col14 from dw2.tbl1_st;"

replaced = re.sub(r'((?!\w+\.\w+).)', '', s)
```

Result set is removing the "." between the database and tablenames.  But I want "." and the whitespace to remain.

```
>> replaced
'dw1dw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_
 stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_
 stdw2tbl1_stdw2tbl1_stdw2'

>> desired_results (Option 1)
'dw1.dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, 
dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, 
dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.tbl1_st, dw2.'
```

Or equally workable:

```
>> desired_results (Option 2)
'dw1 dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st 
dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st 
dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2tbl1_st dw2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, which will work if you know the structure of your string and it is fairly regular, is instead of useing `.` to match everything, using negation to match anything BUT a space or comma:

```
>>> replaced = re.sub(r'((?!\w+\.\w+)[^, ])', '', s)
>>> replaced
'  dw1   dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st,  dw2tbl1_st  dw2tbl1_st,
dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st  dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st,
dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st, dw2tbl1_st  dw2'
```

Or better yet, use `re.findall` and a negative capture group:
, finally joining the resulting list with a space or whatever you want:

```
>>> " ".join(re.findall(r'((?:\w+\.\w+))',s))
'dw1.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st
dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st 
dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st
dw2.tbl1_st dw2.tbl1_st'
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thanks!